# Firebase server value timestamp not converting when using child_added

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Using "child_added" in firebase web, im trying to convert the value of timestamp named "requestTimestamp", but i keep getting a value of "1/1/1970 8:00AM". Whenever i refresh the web page, the timestamp is converted.

```
var urlRef = firebase.database().ref().child("/Rescue Requests/New Rescue 
Requests/");

urlRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) 
var valTimestamp = snapshot.child("requestTimestamp").val();

        var myDate = new Date(valTimestamp);

            //YEAR FORMAT MM/DD/YY
            var result = ((myDate.getMonth().toString().length > 1) ? (myDate.getMonth() + 1) : 
                ('0' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1))) + '/' + ((myDate.getDate().toString().length > 1) ? myDate.getDate() :
                ('0' + myDate.getDate())) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();

            //TIME FORMAT 12 HOURS
            var hours = myDate.getHours();
            var minutes = myDate.getMinutes();
            var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
            hours = hours % 12;
            hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
            minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
            var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

    cellTime.appendChild(document.createTextNode(result +" "+strTime));
```

Comment: The code you shared doesn't show how you add the node. Please create a single, standalone piece of code that reproduces the entire problem. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the node is from the mobile app. 

databaseReference(path).child(node).setValue(ServerValue.Timestamp);

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an android app and I also faced with that problem. It was working true before one month. I think that is a bug of firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The `child_added` event fires only when:

1. The data is initially loaded
2. A new child node is added

When you're adding a new child with a server-side timestamp, a few things happen:

1. The Firebase client where you add the node immediately fires the `child_added` event for the new node, with its best guess at the data.
2. The client sends the data to the server.
3. The server validates the write, ensuring that it's allowed according to the security rules, and expands any markers (i.e. the server-side timestamp marker).
4. The server then sends the result back to the client.
5. The client fires any events needed to reconcile its data with the server's

In that last step it needs to change the timestamp, because its original estimate was probably wrong. So it fires a `child_changed` event for the node in that case.

Similarly if the server rejected the write, because of the security rules, the client will fire a `child_removed` event to reconcile.